# Android Studio Commit tool window disappeared after switching to Non-Modal interface

Tags: android-studio

I always prefer to switch the Commit tool window to Non Modal interface from Android Studio Preferences.

However, after updating to Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 patch I have the following behaviour:

Commit tool window completely disappeared from Android Studio if I untick the Use non-modal interface from Perferences.

[image]

It also disappeared from View -> Tool Windows menu

[image]

If I check Use non-modal commit interface, the Commit Tool Windows re-appears again:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1)Create a list of failed changes = Yes.
2)Specify to use a non-modal binding interface

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).